# How do I invert my DataFrame (the first value --> last value, the last value --> first value)

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am trying to flip (the first value becomes the last value, the last value becomes the first value) the dates column in my DataFrame with `.iloc[:,::-1]` and it does not appear to be working. Here is the sample code:

```
# Clients's Data
file_name = '/Users/x/Desktop/CharlesSchwab.Client.PV.csv'
Client_data = pd.read_csv(file_name)

# Date Info
Client_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Client_data['Date'])
Dates = pd.date_range(min(Client_data["Date"]), max(Client_data["Date"]))
df_Dates = pd.DataFrame(Dates).iloc[:,::-1]
df_Dates.columns = ['Dates']

# Personal Value Info
PV = pd.DataFrame(Client_data["Personal_Value"].str.replace('$','').str.replace(',','').astype(float))

# Adding updated, workable columns back together 
Client1_Data = pd.concat([df_Dates, Personal_Value], axis=1)

# Outputs
Client1_Data
```

## This is what I get:

```
  | Dates      | Personal Value
----------------------
0 | 2018-08-05 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
1 | 2018-08-06 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
2 | 2018-08-07 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
3 | 2018-08-08 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
4 | 2018-08-09 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
```

## This is what I am trying to get:

```
  | Dates      | Personal Value
-------------------------------
0 | 2020-08-05 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
1 | 2020-08-06 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
2 | 2020-08-07 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
3 | 2020-08-08 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
4 | 2020-08-09 | $$$$$$$$$
-------------------------
```

A few notes the dataset `Client_data`, there are 2 columns (both have 732 values) and dates range from Aug 2018 - Aug 2020.

I have tried the same code `.iloc[:, ::-1]` with the Personal Value column and the same thing happens - nothing. The code executes without any errors, it just provides the incorrect assemblage of data. Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Please supply a full reproducible example.  In particular, load your data set from code, rather than reading it from a file: we do not have your input file, so cannot reproduce your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Would maybe `PV.sort_values("Dates", ascending=False)` give you what you need? :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Nikos_N! I tried you suggestion and ended up getting a KeyError: 'Dates'. After that, I iterated your suggestion interchanging the variables (i.e. switching 'Dates' for 'df_Dates') and was still receiving KeyError: 'X Variable'. Any more suggestions?

Comment: You are very welcome :) This means that this dataframe doesn't have a column named "Dates". Is it named "Date" maybe? Would you like to try this?i.e. PV.sort_values("Date", ascending=False)